# mercurial .hgrc

Tags: mercurial

Хочу прописать логин пароль для mercurial, не могу найти файл .hgrc где он может лежать?

Comment: ОС-то у вас какая?

Comment: у меня стоит windows

Comment: `C:\Users\<username>\mercurial.ini` - глобальный, `.hg\hgrc` - локальный конкретного для репозитория.

Comment: Если файла нету, его можно создать по указанным путям

Answer (score 1):

[Configuration files for Mercurial](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#files)

Для Windows (в порядке приоритета):

- /.hg/hgrc (per-repository)
- %USERPROFILE%.hgrc (per-user)
- %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini (per-user)
- %HOME%.hgrc (per-user)
- %HOME%\Mercurial.ini (per-user)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercurial (per-installation)
- \hgrc.d*.rc (per-installation)
- \Mercurial.ini (per-installation)
- /default.d/*.rc (defaults)